# Form Post and upload to AWS S3 in CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I am new to CodeIgniter and i am doing a poc for integrating  CI application with Amazon S3. I have used S3 PHP class from github (https://github.com/psugand/CodeIgniter-S3) and able to list buckets and list object from bucket to view file. 
My problem is first i am not able to post the values to controller from the views form and then need to check on how to upload the files to s3. Also kindly What is the use of URI in putObject function?

Below are the Controller & View file. Kindly let me know how we can do form post to controller and from then upload to S3.

My Controller File - S3demo.php

```
class S3demo extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        //Var Declaration
        $data['bucketName'] = "demacrtest";

        // Load Library
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('s3');

        // Get all required Data
        $data['bucket_list'] = $this->s3->listBuckets();
        $header_data['title'] = "CI and S3 Demo";
        $data['object_list'] = $this->s3->getBucket($data['bucketName']);


        // Load Views
        $this->load->view('common/header', $header_data);
        $this->load->view('s3_demo', $data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }

    public function doUploadtoS3(){
        echo "in";

        //Var Declaration
        $data['bucketName'] = "demacrtest";
        $uri = "dms/";
// Load Library
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('s3');

        // GET DATA POST FROM FORM
        $data = array(
        'files' => $this->input->post('uploadedfiles')
        );
        // DISPLAY DATA
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);

        // PUT with custom headers:
        $put = S3::putObject(
            S3::inputFile($data),
            $data['bucketName'],
            $uri,
            S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
            array(),
            array( // Custom $requestHeaders
                "Cache-Control" => "max-age=315360000",
                "Expires" => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+5 years"))
            )
        );
    }
}
```

My View File - s3_demo.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>List of S3 buckets</h1>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($bucket_list as $bucket){?>
                    <li><?php echo $bucket;?></li>
                <?php  }?>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>List of objects in bucket - <?php echo $bucketName; ?></h1>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($object_list as $objects){?>
                    <li><?php echo $objects['name']; ?></li>
                <?php  }?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="upload-form">
            <h3>Upload to S3 Form</h3>
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="s3demo/doUploadtoS3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class ="control-label col-sm-3">Upload</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input id="input-2" name="uploadedfiles[]" type="file" class="file">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
               </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also tried to use CI Form functions but it is of no use
 `<?php echo form_open('s3demo/doUploadtoS3') ?> `
Even this is not Working...

Answer (score 0):

Got This Working Finally... Changed uploadtos3 function. `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');` got me working

```
 public function doUploadtoS3(){

    //Var Declaration
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 1000;

    // Load Library
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->load->library('s3');

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('uploadedfiles'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }
    // CONSTRUCT URI
    $uri = "dms/images/".time()."-".$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
    $bucketName = "demacrtest";

    // DISPLAY DATA
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);

    // PUT with custom headers:
    $put = S3::putObject(
        S3::inputFile($data['upload_data']['full_path']),
        $bucketName,
        $uri,
        S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
        array(),
        array( // Custom $requestHeaders
            "Cache-Control" => "max-age=315360000",
            "Expires" => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+5 years"))
        )
    );
    var_dump($put);
}
```

Comment: Sites Which Helped Me [CI LINK](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)
[;S3 LINK](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#putObject)

Answer (score 0):

```
// PUT with custom headers:
$put = S3::putObject(
    S3::inputFile($data['upload_data']['full_path']),
    $bucketName,
    $uri,
    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
    array(),
    array( // Custom $requestHeaders
        "Cache-Control" => "max-age=315360000",
        "Expires" => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+5 years"))
    )
);
var_dump($put);
```